# Chrome Extension: how to find which content script js file is running using dev tools?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I have chrome extension. I know how to find which line of codes in background script file is executing at this moment through Extension->Background script.
But  how can I find which content script js file is running now using dev tools?
Thanks

Comment: I would just stop the execution in the debugger

Comment: Stop and? I cannot find content script js file in the dev tools